# Trouble adding conditional to page-title.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I am building my first D8 theme and I am new to Twig. I am trying to add a class to the h1 title tag on the home by editing page-title.html.twig, but I can't get it to take. Here is my code

```
{% set body_class = '' %}
{% if title == 'Welcome to My Website' %}
    {% set body_class = 'home-page-title' %}
{% endif %}

{{ title_prefix }}
    <h1{{ title_attributes.addClass(body_class) }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{{ title_suffix }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. The method you are using is not consistent if you change the page title to something else, or use another page as your landing page.

There are two ways to solve this:

### The long way, using `hook_preprocess_html()`

Instead of this, I recommend targeting the `<h1>` tag through a body selector, and add there a special class for front page through `hook_preprocess_html()`. This is a cleaner solution, and you can target other elements as well.

This code would go to your `YOUR_THEME.theme` file:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Add a custom class determining if we're on the front page.
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'front';
  }
  else {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'not-front';
  }
}
```

In your `html.html.twig` file you need to have:

```
<body{{ attributes }}>
```

Then in your CSS file, you would use:

```
body.front h1.page-title {
  /* Your styles. */
}
```

### The short way, using only twig - by [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4)

The `root_path` variable provided to you by [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8) will be set to `FALSE` when you are on the front page. This means that you can use it as condition argument, and give different class to the `body` element.

Here's an example:

```
<body{{ attributes.addClass(root_path ? 'not-front' : 'front') }}>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect solution, you can even make it shorter or doing it all in twig by using the variable `root_path` which is FALSE if the page is front (see template_preprocess_html() in theme.inc)

Comment: Ha! That's a good one - will include it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Both of these work great! I'm going with the short way.